# What format should my Blackberry application be in to submit to App World?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-world

I already have an installation using .alx/.cod files that we use to install our Blackberry application via Desktop Manager, and also an "over the air" install version consisting of a .jad file and .cod files (uncompressed and no larger that 64K as specified by the mime type) that is downloaded from our website.

What format should I upload the application to App World as?

I gather all the files should be in a zip file but apart from that I'm struggling to find much more information on the RIM website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RIM has a document with the exact requirements for a submission bundle for an app for BlackBerry AppWorld:
"[Contents of a .zip file for a release](https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberryworld/preparing_your_zip_file.html)"

Comment: This is actually the best answer so far.

Comment: Did you actually use this method with success? I did, with very limited result. Most of the information is not read by AppWorld (version, min OS, platform and devices need to be set by hand anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Look at [section 5 b](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/appworld/faq.jsp) in the App World FAQ.

It mentions among many other things, COD files. The plural is because, you need to submit a COD file for each OS version you are planning to support.

Comment: Thanks-that looks like the checklist I need. I guess there is no need for an alx or jad file in this case.

Comment: @John Sibly, no, I think the App World thingy is the equivalent of the jad and so on. Especially how your app will not appear for OS versions you have not supplied a COD file for.