# create a file bundle to submit for a blackberry app to app world

Tags: file, blackberry, submit, bundle, blackberry-world

How do you create a file bundle to submit for a blackberry app to app world?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What format should my Blackberry application be in to submit to App World?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076580/what-format-should-my-blackberry-application-be-in-to-submit-to-app-world)

Answer (score 2):

I already answered this on StackOverflow question "[What format should my Blackberry application be in to submit to App World?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076580/what-format-should-my-blackberry-application-be-in-to-submit-to-app-world/5078576#5078576)"

> RIM has a document with the exact
>   requirements for a submission bundle
>   for an app for BlackBerry AppWorld:
>   "[Contents of a .zip file for a
>   release](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25819/Options_for_a_zip_file_for_a_release_664581_11.jsp)"

Answer (score 0):

Link has changed. You can now get the info here:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/47831/1278467.jsp

Essentially though, just add the .cod file to the file bundle.